# using map lambda to destroy widgets tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I'm learning some in built functions for python, and I tried using the map and lambda function to destroy child widgets of a canvas, but it didn't work.

Here's what I tried:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

C = Canvas(root, bg='red',width=400,height=400)
C.pack()

Label(C,text='Label').pack()

Button(C,text='Button').pack()

map(lambda child: child.destroy(), C.winfo_children())

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` return an *iterable*, the function passed to `map` will only be applied on the items of the *iterable* when it is consumed/iterated.

You can use `any()`/`list()`/`tuple()` on the *map iterable* to consume its items, so that the function is applied:

```
any(map(lambda child: child.destroy(), C.winfo_children()))
```

or simply using *list comprehension* if you want one-liner:

```py
[child.destroy() for child in C.winfo_children()]
```

Comment: Thanks, I already done the list comprehension one, wanted to see if I could do it with map, is it true that in this case, the map way is faster ?

Comment: just timed it, it seems the list comprehension is faster for some reason